# Need help writing .bat file which changes all file permissions in a folder to Everyone

Tags: batch-file, cmd, permissions, google-drive-api

I appreciate your time so I won't take much of it.  Here's what I'm trying to do: I want to create a .bat file that, when executed, will open the Command Prompt program, change directory to a folder (located on the C:), then execute a line of code that will change the file permission status of all files in that folder to Everyone.  I intend to create a Windows task that will run this .bat file everyday.  I understand how to setup the Windows task, but I can't figure out exactly how the .bat file should be written.  Can anyone help?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
ECHO OFF

[Tab]Start "" C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

ECHO OFF

[Tab]Prompt cd cd:\google drive

ECHO OFF

[Tab]Prompt cacls *.* /t /e /g everyone:f
```

If you're interested, here's why I'm trying to create this .bat file:

I use a single Google Drive account on two file server computers, one in each of two offices.  Each office has this file server and about 10 client computers.  The client computers access files on the shared Google Drive folder (located on the file server) and occasionally add/edit/delete files.  Google Drive does a great job of keeping all files synced between the two offices, but one problem I have is that if office A adds a file, the only computer in office B that can see it is the file server.  I have to change the file permission to "Everyone" using the file server in office B before any of the client computers in office B can see the file.  Over time, it's become very annoying to manually change the file permission every day and I'm looking for a shortcut.  Please let me know if you can think of a better one.

Comment: If you are using windows 7 or later, you should use `ICACLS` since `CACLS` is deprecated.  So what is the problem you are having with this batch file?  Does it run?  What is the output?

Comment: When I double click the file I see the command prompt window appear for a second, then it disappears. After that, it doesn't appear that anything is happening. When I check a file whose permission should've been changed by the batch file it is not changed, so I'm assuming the batch file didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Put a `pause` at the end of the batch to make it pause waiting for a keypress.  this way you will see the output of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the commands right then this is a batch script with them.

The `&&` will run the following command only if the `cd` command was successful.

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\google drive" && cacls *.* /t /e /g everyone:f
```

Comment: Thank you. I created a batch file with only the content you provided, but double-clicking it results in the comment I made to the answer above yours in this thread. Any suggestions?

Comment: Put `pause` as the last line and try it.  You will see any error messages then.